# implementation butterworth filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I have an accelerometer 3 axis.

As far as we know that acceleration is the sum of static acceleration (gravity) and dynamic acceleration.

my goal's to extract a gravity acceleration which will show me the direction of the device.

i will apply a butterworth filter to extract a gravity acceleration. but i have a problem in choosing cut-off frequency and a filter order.

T = 0.16 s ; %Time of sample rate so Fs = 1/0.16 ; % sampling rate? is this correct?

After reading a few articles, i found that the cut-off varie between 0.1 to 0.5 , here i will choose a 0.5 (because as i don't know they are based on their choice.

this is the program which i will execute in Matlab to extract gravity acceleration from the 3 axis.

```
Fc = 0.5 ; %cut-off frequency

 Fs = 6.26 hz (1/0.16) ; % sampling rate order = 4;

[b,a] = butter(order,fc(fs/2),'low');

x = filter (b,a,x0);
y = filter(b,a,y0);

z = filter(b,a,z0);
```

Comment: So, you dont get nice results with that? what do you expect, what do you get? throw us a bone.

Comment: thanaks for your reply. i'm stuck in choosing cut-off frequency, here i choose arbitrary cut-off = 0.5. in other hand, when i normlaize a cut-off frequency ( fc*(fc/2)) it gives me an error in matlab because cut-off should be within interval [0,1]

Comment: `fc*(fc/2)` is **not normalized**.  You need to **divide** whatever frequency you have with `Fs/2`, and obviously it can't be **larger** than this.  `Fs/2` is your Nyquist frequency, which represents the total bandwidth of your signal.  The cutoff frequency of `0.5` is the **normalized frequency**.  In reality, this is actually equal to `Fs/4`.  Try values between `[0.5,1]` in the normalized range or from `[Fs/4, Fs/2]` in the actual range.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. as we say ,i found in these two links that Fc = FS/4 (http://www.cwc-ae.com/product/kadadc132),and in other link i found this : If the Cutoff Frequency is less than Fs/2L (see below) then the filter will be a lowpass; otherwise it will be a highpass. Also, the Cutoff Frequency cannot be exactly Fs/2L, and cannot be greater than Fs/L with L= 2; in my case and to calculate a normalized cut off frequency = (Fs/4)/(Fs/2) = 0.5 and as i will use a low pass filter , i should varying cut-off between [0.5,1] as we said?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is, you "slow" the measurements down with a butterworth filter. Thus, in practice you try to get rid of the "fast" part. What this means in frequency domain is: you want a lowpass (low frequency = slow signal goes through, while high = fast gets filtered out). So I guess with what you know already you should be able to find a reasonable value.

Generally for estimating the angles you have gyroscopes at hand. Then you would rather go for kalman filtering, since this doesn't add as much of a delay to your measurements (if it is time dependent).

As already commented, keep in mind, that you are dealing with sampled data (nyquist freq. is a natural restriction).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The problem here that i should use just an accelerometer 3D, i know that it will be so better if i use a fusion sensors and using a complemantary filter but it is a suggest of my professor. if i apply low pass butterworth filter, it can't give me a good results? Thanks in advance

Comment: Really depending on what good is. It can't be fast for example. How would it be, if you can't trust the fast measurements of your accelerometer?
Complementing a filter is a pretty basic way that doesn't use more thinkin than: this can be multiplied and added together. Kalman filtering for example is under circumstances optimal! Everything you need to know depends on your application,... so maybe supply more info for better answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. in my case, i tried to collect acceleration data in first time and analyze it to know a direction of our device(Sensortag which contains an accelerometer),i'm looking for filtring gravity from acceleration data. i know that it will be better if i will use an accelerometer+ an gyroscope, but as i said in my last post that it is the suggestion of my professor.

Answer (score 0):

Cutoff frequency depends upon the interested range of signal you want to extract from a noisy signal. Assume: You use your mobile phone inside the trouser pocket and collect raw data during activities. Then your cutoff frequency is directly related to the rate of human activity( Eg: Running, walking ,jogging etc). 
Note: As the filter order N increases, the actual frequency responses approach the ideal.
Filter order will also be a factor of the signal you want to extract to analyse.
Refer this publication for more info:
A gyroscopic data based pedometer algorithm by Jayalath.S
Link:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6553971&queryText%3DA+gyroscopic+data+based+pedometer+algorithm